# Don't process the <form> if the <input> DOESN'T contain an underscore

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

Form:

```
<form action="goto.php" method="post" name="myform" id="myform" onsubmit="return formSubmit(this);" class="form-wrapper cf">
  <input name="statusid" autocomplete="off" id="statusid" placeholder="Enter ID Here" type="text">
  <input name="submit_btn" class="submit" id="submit_btn" value="" placeholder="submit" >
</form>
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/FEF7D/4/

Some users submit an ID that has only numbers in it (e.g. 981734844).
And some users submit an ID that has underscore "_" (without quotes) in it (e.g. 28371366_243322).

What I want to do is NOT allowing the users that submit an ID with ONLY numbers in it (e.g. 89172318) to process the form action.

In other words:

82174363278423: Don't allow to process the form action

21489724893249_2918423: Allow to process the form action

Is it possible to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about letters and other characters / symbols? It's probably best if you provide a *whitelist* pattern

Comment: Users don't need to submit a word or a letter, the form only accepts numbers. But I want the form to accept ONLY numbers that have underscore in between (e.g. 2894723489327_384323).

Comment: FYI your submit button should be `type="submit"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

```
function formSubmit(form) {
    // create a regex to test for the numbers + underscore + numbers pattern
    var rx = /^\d+_\d+$/,
        test = rx.test(form.statusid.value);

    test || alert('You need to enter an ID with underscore in it.');
    return test;
}
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/FEF7D/7/

Comment: It will not allow underscore as first character.

Comment: @FizerKhan And why should it? The OP specifically wants *numbers + underscore + numbers*

Answer (score 0):

you need to use java script validation and in that you can use following code:

```
  if ( String.indexOf('_') != -1 ) {
        // your form processing code..
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can do that. There are a number of solutions. For example, you can split your input string into an array using the underscore as the split divider and if your array has two entries, you know you've got a single underscore. e.g. Something like this (untested snippet to illustrate - you also need to add numeric checks for each part of the array so you probably want to assign the split to a variable if going with this approach):

```
$('form').submit(function(event)
{
    if (myinputvar.split('_').length ! = 2)
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
    // do the rest of your submission here
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do any form validation in `onsubmit` of form.

HTML

```
<form name="myform" id="myform" onsubmit="return formSubmit(this);" class="form-wrapper cf" action="goto.php" method="post">
  <input name="statusid" autocomplete="off" id="statusid" placeholder="Enter ID Here" type="text">
  <input type="submit" name="submit_btn" class="submit" id="submit_btn" value="" placeholder="submit" >
</form>
```

JavaScript

```
// Do validation of form
function formSubmit(formObj) {
    // Only allowable character is numeric or underscore 
    if (!/^[_0-9]*$/.test(formObj.statusid.value)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Hi, can I show an alert saying "You need to enter an ID with underscore in it." for the users that DON'T have underscore in the input after submitting? Thanks

Comment: Better show inline under the input of status id or above the form. Try to avoid alert popup which will not professional.

Comment: Can I get an inline code for the users that DONT have an underscore in the input? I am sorry that I am not good in HTML or JS.

Comment: @user3213765 You know this will accept something like `abc_123` or even just `_`, right?

Comment: @user3213765 I have doubt, do you want to allow _ or not allow _?

Comment: @Fizer-Khan I want to allow an underscore that has numbers around it (e.g. 7834632842_234324)

Comment: @Phil the script you gave me doesn't allow _ that has no numbers around it. And that's what I was looking for :) 
So it's not accepting just _

Comment: @Phil & Fizer-Khan, is it possible that the users can delete the javascript you gave me using the Inspect Element (Inspector)? 
And then they will be able to enter an ID WITHOUT underscore in it? or they can't do that?

Comment: @user3213765 You can't solely rely on client-side validation. Users can always get around it

Comment: Yes, i agree with Phil. You have to do server side validation too.

Comment: @Phil & Fizer, Submitting an ID without underscore makes my server slower, that's why I am trying to disable them. Is there any way to not let the users remove the script from on the Inspector? Or a way that will make the script work 100% for all users and they can't change anything in it? 
Thanks

Comment: @user3213765 No, there is not. Your claim that IDs without underscores make your server slower is completely nonsensical

Answer (score -2):

The two answers above will work (just strip out Neil's jquery). 
Another option is

```
function formSubmit(form){
   var statusid=document.getElementById("statusid");
    if(statusid.value.search("_")===-1){
        alert('ID must have an underscore "_".');
    }
};
```

unfortunately, for some reason I can't get that to work with jsfiddle, it's telling me `formSubmit is not a function`, but clearly it is. Either way, javascript has a 'search' method on strings.

Comment: The `form` variable (an `HTMLFormElement` object) does not have a `preventDefault` method.